# How do I get Visual Studio Online to do a Build Cordova/PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, tfs, azure-devops, phonegap-build

How do I get Visual Studio Online to do a Build/Continious Intergration-Delivery for Cordova? 
The only examples below are for installing to your own TFS installation. The CI build templates for VSO is Java/Android or C++/iOS not Cordova/PhoneGap.

https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/apps/mobile/cordova-build?view=vsts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/apps/mobile/cordova-command?view=vsts

Comment: Can you share your current build definition settings?

Comment: How do you create Cordova project? You can create a empty build definition, then add related tasks to build Cordova project.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [Team Foundation Server guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/index?view=vsts), they don't seem to support Cordova apps.

Why don't your try [Visual Studio Community 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) instead? This includes the Tools for Apache Cordova and it works perfectly fine.